# Questions regarding Post-Stratification and Imputation

Tags: r, data-imputation, survey-weights, poststratification

This is my first try in making a reproducible sample, so I hope it goes well and is comprehensive.

Based on a (German) survey among young people of Generation Z, I ask: *Does volunteering have a positive impact on the perception of young people's life satisfaction?*
When asked about possible confounders, I suggest that material satisfaction (are material desires usually fulfilled?) might affect volunteering as well as life satisfaction.

My questions are:

- Is it meaningful to post-stratify on the strata (state) or should I chose another variable for this?
- Also, I am insecure about my approach for imputation. I imputed on the three variables of my assumes relationship and left out weight and strata as they do not have missing data. Would it make sense to not impute one of the variables I used? Is "imputationList" the correct last step of an imputation process or am I missing anything?

These are the packages I have currently loaded.

```
pacman::p_load(tidyverse, readr, haven, naniar, survey, dplyr, mice, mitools)
```

This is a sample of my prepared dataset

```
genZ_prep <- structure(list(weight = c(0.938, 1.173, 0.947, 0.891, 0.799, 
0.976, 0.98, 0.888, 1.045, 1.158, 1.38, 0.781, 0.976, 1.039, 
1.38, 1.069, 1.006, 1.033, 0.832, 1.062, 1.12, 0.904, 1.009, 
0.794, 0.687, 1.115, 0.98, 1.03, 1.063, 1.38), life_satisf = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("satisfied", 
"unsatisfied"), class = "factor"), mat_satisf = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("yes", 
"no"), class = "factor"), volunteer = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("yes", 
"no"), class = "factor"), state = c("Hessen", "Baden-Württemberg", 
"Nordrhein-Westfalen", "Rheinland-Pfalz", "Bayern", "Bayern", 
"Sachsen-Anhalt", "Niedersachsen", "Nordrhein-Westfalen", "Schleswig-Holstein", 
"Nordrhein-Westfalen", "Thüringen", "Nordrhein-Westfalen", "Niedersachsen", 
"Niedersachsen", "Nordrhein-Westfalen", "Nordrhein-Westfalen", 
"Bayern", "Nordrhein-Westfalen", "Hessen", "Bayern", "Nordrhein-Westfalen", 
"Bayern", "Nordrhein-Westfalen", "Nordrhein-Westfalen", "Nordrhein-Westfalen", 
"Hessen", "Sachsen", "Baden-Württemberg", "Nordrhein-Westfalen"
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))
```

**Encode your survey data into a Svydesign-Object. Do not include weights yet. Make sure the encoding matches your mentioned/assumed sampling strategy above (srs, str, cluster, multistage sampling etc.)**

*The sampling strategy of my dataset is quota sampling. I have therefore included the variable "state" into my prepared dataset to build a svydesign-object*

```
genZ_prep_str_nowe <-
  svydesign(data = genZ_prep,
            id = ~ 1,
            strata = ~ state)
```

**Re-Encode your surveydesign-object with the weights that are provided in your data set.**

```
genZ_prep_str_we <-
  svydesign(data = genZ_prep,
            id = ~ 1,
            weights = ~ weight)
```

**Build a weighted svydesign object based on a re-weighting-technique *(we discussed Post-Stratification and Raking)* that was covered in the sessions. Justify the variables you weighted on.**

```
set.seed(12345)

state_popdist <- tibble(
  state = c("Baden-Württemberg", "Bayern", "Berlin", "Brandenburg", "Bremen", 
            "Hamburg", "Hessen", "Mecklenburg-Vorpommern", "Niedersachsen",
            "Nordrhein-Westfalen", "Rheinland-Pfalz", "Saarland", "Sachsen", 
            "Sachsen-Anhalt", "Schleswig-Holstein", "Thüringen"),
  Freq =  c(11103043,  13140183, 3664088, 2531071, 680130, 1852478, 6293154, 
            1610774, 8003421, 17925570, 4098391, 983991, 4056941, 2180684, 
            2910875, 2120237))

data_postStr <- postStratify(design = genZ_prep_str_nowe, strata = ~state, 
                             population = state_popdist)
```

**Check if you have any types of missing values in your data.**

```
miss_var_summary(genZ_prep)
```

**Impute and briefly justify why and how you imputed (justify which variables and techniques you used for imputation).**

```
pred_matrix <- quickpred(genZ_prep)
pred_matrix[, c("weight", "state")] <- 0
pred_matrix

imp_meth <- 
  mice(genZ_prep,
       m = 1,
       maxit = 1,
       predictorMatrix = pred_matrix,
       print = FALSE)$method %>% 
  as.vector()

imp_meth


imp <-
  mice(genZ_prep,
       method = imp_meth,
       predictorMatrix = pred_matrix,
       seed = 12345,
       print = FALSE)

imp$m

imp_data <-
  imputationList(map(seq(imp$m), mice::complete, data = imp))
```

Weight is not a response, so imputation in this case is not meaningful. For the strata (states) no missing values exist. Imputation method is logreg (logistic regression) since the variables are binary.